# Grunt recompile since last run

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js, grunt-contrib-watch

I have grunt watch setup so when i`m developing my files are automatically compiled, but after I pull i need to "touch" the files in order to trigger recompile the new files in case watch was not running while I pulled, is there a generic way to make grunt track last edit for files without having to "touch" the new files or should i just have grunt watch running before I pull (which while writing this seems like an adequate solution)?

Comment: why isn't it always running?

Comment: @vsync well merging files might be a good time to turn it off, wont you agree, also when you start your computer is a time when grunt is not running yet, when you switch to another project is another time its not running (yet)...

Comment: It should always run. always. no matter what. don't do anything that is related to what you work on before making sure it is running.

Answer (score 1):

Just have the watch run while you make the pull, or just run the tasks manually--the kind of detailed tracking you're suggesting just seems like overkill to me. Keep it simple!